# SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, java.lang.NullPointerException: []

Tags: apex, email, email-template, singleemailmessage

I am getting this error message:

> Message: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, java.lang.NullPointerException: []
>   Stack Trace:
>   Class.MessagingHelper.send: line 4, column 1
>   Class.RESTController.sendEmail: line 66, column 1
>   Class.RESTController.handlePost: line 41, column 1
>   Line Number: 4
>   Type Name: System.EmailException

When I run this code:

```
private static void sendEmail(Blob attachment, Id recordId) {

    Id targetObjectId = getContact();

    if (targetObjectId == null){
        throw new CustomException('Unable to find contact');
    }

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setTemplateId(getEmailTemplateId());    
    mail.setWhatId(recordId);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId);
    mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(OrgWideEmailAddressHelper.getNoReplyOrgWideEmailAddressId());             
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
    mail.setOptOutPolicy('FILTER');
    mail.setFileAttachments(MessagingHelper.createEmailFileAttachment(FILE_TITLE, attachment));

    MessagingHelper.send(mail);
}
```

Which uses these helper methods:

```
public without sharing class MessagingHelper {

    public static void send(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail) {
        MessagingHelper.handleSendEmailResult(Messaging.sendEmail(MessagingHelper.createEmailMessages(mail)));
    }

    public static List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> createEmailFileAttachment(String filename, Blob body) {
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment emailAttachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        emailAttachment.setFileName(filename);
        emailAttachment.setBody(body);
        return new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> {emailAttachment};
    }

    public static List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> createEmailMessages(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail) {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        messages.add(mail);
        return messages;
    }

    public static void handleSendEmailResult(List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results) {
        for(Messaging.SendEmailResult result :results) {                                    
            if(!result.IsSuccess()) {                    
                List<Messaging.SendEmailError> errors = result.getErrors();
                if (errors.size() > 0){
                    Messaging.SendEmailError err = errors[0];
                    System.debug(err.getMessage());       
                }                   
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

What is causing it and how do I fix it?

Comment: You don't need to call the class' name to call its own methods. Odd line to throw that error...`Messaging` or `MessagingHelper` would have to be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was caused by incorrect permissions.

The `RESTController` is accessed via a public `Site` and the `Site Profile` needed access to the Email Template `relatedTo` object so that it could correctly merge the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same issue and I've boiled it down to community license:

`Customer Community Plus Login` works while

`Customer Community Login` doesn't.

Unsure of exact cause